# Trying to run the Camel route thru CamelContext with autoStartup set to false

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have the following Camel route which I am trying to run thru the CamelContext directly with autoStartup set to false
@Component

```
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class S3IntegratorRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Value("${base.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("#{${queryParams}}")
    private Map<String, String> query;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jsonConversionProcessor")
    private Processor jsonProcessor;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        String queryParams = Util.buildQueryParams(query);
        from("timer:mytimer?repeatCount=1")
        // from("timer://manualRestart?repeatCount=1")
            .routeId("manualRestart").autoStartup(false)
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple(queryParams))
            .to(url).process(jsonProcessor);
    }
}
```

I am trying to run this route in the main application class as shown below-

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class CollibraApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CollibraApiApplication.class, args);

        S3IntegratorRoute s3IntegratorRoute = ctx.getBean(S3IntegratorRoute.class);

        ExtendedCamelContext camelContext = ctx.getBean(ExtendedCamelContext.class);

        camelContext.addRoutes(s3IntegratorRoute);

        camelContext.start();
    }
}
```

But when I start this spring boot application I am getting following message in console log and the route is not getting started-

> ] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Skipping starting of route manualRestart as it's configured with autoStartup=false
> 2023-03-30 14:41:50.451 []  INFO 25808 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Total 1 routes, of which 0 are started
> 2023-03-30 14:41:50.453 []  INFO 25808 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.3.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.030 seconds

Can someone please give an example of how to run this route directly thru CamelContext or is there any other way?

Expecting to run the Camel Route directly instead of autoStartup

Comment: I don't understand `Expecting to run the Camel Route directly instead of autoStartup`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `autoStartup(false)` then Camel does **NOT** start the route, and so when you start `CamelContext` (Camel itself) then 0 routes are started as you can see from the log. This is expected. If you want the route to start then remove `autoStartup` or set its value to `true`.

See the docs on the website about autoStartup for more details.

Comment: Hi  Claus, Thanks for the reply. When I set autoStartup to true then even if I comment the below 2 lines in my main class in spring boot application then also it starts the route automatically,I dont want to do that. I want my route to be triggered manually by injecting the CamelContext(for e.g in controller or service layer) and then start the route thru CamelContext. Currently it seems that below 2 lines have no effect in starting the route as I mentioned that when I comment these lines then it automatically starts.
camelContext.addRoutes(s3IntegratorRoute);

camelContext.start();